# Can a creature be destroyed just before Shalai gives it hexproof?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

At the start of the turn (it is B’s turn):

Player A has a 2/2 [Walking Ballista](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bWalking%20Ballista%5d) on the battlefield.
Player B has a 1/1 creature on the battlefield.

Player B casts [Shalai, Voice of plenty](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bShalai%2c%20Voice%20of%20plenty%5d), which gives hexproof to B’s creatures.
Can player A, in response to B’s casting Shalai, then activate ballista’s remove a counter ability to deal lethal damage to B’s 1/1 creature?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can destroy the creature before it gains Hexproof.

Shalai's ability is a [static ability](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Static_ability) which does not take effect until after casting Shalai resolves (i.e. the spell leaves the stack and Shalai enters the battlefield).<sup>[604.2](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Static_ability)</sup>  While Shalai is still on the stack, the static ability is not "active" and has no effect.

Before Shalai resolves, Player A is given [priority](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Timing_and_priority) and can then use Walking Ballista's ability, which is also placed on the stack.  This ability will resolve before Shalai, killing the 1/1 creature before Shalai can give it Hexproof.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Because the hexproof source would not have resolved yet, and thus still be on the stack, a targeted ability can be added to the stack in response. The targeting ability would resolve first and then the hexproof source would.